# How to let processes run after closing ssh connection

Tags: remote-access

I need to run a long evaluation on my research group machines at university (Scientific Linux 6 , Mathematica 9).
I just connect via ssh and work on math text-based environment.
I can't find a way to let MathKernel processes go on when I log-out the ssh connection.
I tried to put them in background using & and nohup, and I also tried to "daemonize" them, but no one of these attempts worked. 
Processes start properly, and they generate the output files they are supposed to. I can monitor them using "top" command on a secondary shell, and I can see them die when I close the primary shell or I exit the ssh connection on it.
I read about some issues Mathematica has with csh/tsch shells, but i did not find a valid solution to my problem.
Can someone suggest a possible solution?

Thanks

Comment: [GNU screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [NX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology)

Comment: Thanks, @mmal . I forgot to specify I cannot install anything on the severs because I am not system administrator. By the way, I knew about Screen, but I didn't know about NX tech, so thanks for improving my knowledge.

Comment: @DomenicoGuida, when you say you use & and nohup, are you still using an interactive session, meaning do you see "In[1]:= "?

Comment: Unless execute permission is denied on home directories, then you can still build and use programs like `screen` without being a system administrator. It is not necessary for these programs to be in `/usr/bin` to run. Just build it with `--prefix=<somewhere in your home directory>`. Or, if your system administrator(s) are helpful, just ask them to install GNU `screen` for you. It is a very commonly used program.

Comment: @JasonB, I only see "Launching Kernels..." and nothing else. If I launch a short process and wait, the prompt comes back when process finishes. If I close the terminal window all related processes stop.

Comment: @DomenicoGuida You can still install these tools into your home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is how you are already doing things, let me know.  But for me, running on a remote kernel means running in batch mode; no method of accessing a GUI, or using an interactive prompt is as reliable.

So, on the remote machine, create a text file called "test.m" in the directory where `math` usually starts, and put the following contents inside it

```
Do[
  Pause[5.];
  Print["paused for " <> IntegerString[5 n] <> " seconds"];
  , {n, 12}];


Export["test.dat", {#, #^2} & /@ Range[500]];

Exit[]
```

This will run for two minutes, then output a simple matrix to a file.

Now you log in to the remote server via ssh and run that command via

```
nohup nice math -noprompt -run "<<test.m" > output &
```

What that is doing is opening `math` without a prompt, and running the single line `<<test.m`

The output from the `Print` command should go to the file `output`, and the matrix should go the file "test.dat".  It should run for 2 minutes so that is plenty of time to log out, wait, then log back in to see if the files were created.

I learned this from @Jens, detailed on [this page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/Mathematica.html).  At the time, I was running calculations on the University of Oregon's cluster (where Jens is a professor), and we had a really awesome site license so I could submit hundred of Mathematica jobs - which is why I didn't learn any other programming language until leaving grad school.

Comment: I think it may be better to not to use `Exit[]` in the scipt (since it can also be used in interactive session, or nested in other script) and use `math -noprompt -run "<<test.m; Exit[]; > output &` instead.